# How to change the value of the first object from the second?

Tags: javascript

Can I get an explanation for why assigning values from another object is not possible?
And how to change the value of the first object from the second?

```
class Test {
  obj1 = {
    obj1Value: [1, 2, 3],
  };

  obj2 = {
    changeValue() {
      this.obj1.obj1Value = [2, 2, 2];
    },
  };
}

let test = new Test();

console.log(test.obj1.value); // [1, 2, 3]
test.obj2.changeValue();
console.log(test.obj1.value); // TypeError: Cannot set property 'obj1Value' of undefined ???
```

Comment: You're mixing the usage of `obj1.value` and `obj1.obj1Value` - is this a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `test.obj2.changeValue()`, using `this` inside of `changeValue` refers to `obj2` rather than the `Test` class because of the way `this` bindings work, try using an arrow function instead so that `this` is inherited to refer to `Test`:

```js
class Test {
  obj1 = {
    obj1Value: [1, 2, 3],
  };

  obj2 = {
    changeValue: () => {
      this.obj1.obj1Value = [2, 2, 2];
    },
  };
}

let test = new Test();

console.log(test.obj1.obj1Value);
test.obj2.changeValue();
console.log(test.obj1.obj1Value);
```

Without going into full detail on `this` bindings (more detailed info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)), when a function is a property on an object, and you call it through the object, i.e. `obj.func()`, `this` will refer to the object it is called through, i.e. `obj`. If you instead did `f = obj.func; f()`, then `this` would behave differently. It's all about how you call the function. Using arrow functions (also known as anonymous functions) instead inherit the `this` keyword from its parent context, which is why you can do `test.obj2.changeValue()` without `this` referring to `obj2`

Comment: @iLoveJS no problem, I would recommend reading up on how `this` works so you can avoid these kinds of confusion (and also learn how to leverage `this` in a much better way)

Answer (score 1):

Using Arrow Functions you are able to reach the right scope. Like this:

```
  obj1 = {
    obj1Value: [1, 2, 3],
  };

  obj2 = {
    changeValue: () => {
      this.obj1.obj1Value = [2, 2, 2];
    },
  };
```

Comment: @GM-atteoni this has nothing to do with scope, `this` binding is an entirely different thing and is instead dictated by how a function is called at runtime

Comment: Yes it has. Knowing about variable scopes should give you the base for understanding `this` binding. The error he got was because of the wrong scope calling `this.`, caused by the wrong declaration of the function.

Comment: @GM-atteoni I would suggest you also read up more about `this` binding. What you are referring to has nothing to do with _scope_, and instead has to do with _context_. The error he got was **not** because of "the wrong scope calling `this`" (which I'm not even sure what that's supposed to mean), but instead it was because of `this` referring to the wrong context due to the way the function was called. Changing this to an arrow function still creates a scope the same way a normal function would, the only difference is that it inherits `this` from its parent _context_

Comment: @GM-atteoni variable scope is in no way related to `this` binding, because variable scope is 100% about where code is located in a file (aka defined at compile-time) whereas `this` context is 100% about how a function is called (aka defined at runtime)

Comment: The problem with our friend is already solved. I'm trying to give him a base to understand the error source. In my opinion, learning `this` after learning about variable scopes can cause some confusion. You have your own space up there to say what you want to him, please don't blame my point of view.

Comment: @GM-atteoni I'm not blaming you at all, but if you are going to be posting answers and trying to teach things to others, then you need to be open to hearing from others if what you are describing is incorrect, because incorrect or misleading things should not be taught. Your answer itself was correct and was good insight, but the comments about the problem being related to variable scope was not correct and therefore is not something that you should be teaching someone who is trying to learn

Comment: So, tell me what is incorrect: 1- "Knowing about variable scopes should give you the base for understanding this binding" or 2- "Using Arrow Functions you are able to reach the right scope". 3- "The error he got was because of the wrong scope calling this." 4- "caused by the wrong declaration of the function"

Comment: No needed, the problem was caused by the wrong way of declaring a function. The consequence was a wrong usage of `this`.

Comment: @GM-atteoni yes that is true, Although, what I'm trying to get at is that even if you didn't declare the function as an arrow function, you could still solve the problem with other solutions such as `test.obj2.changeValue = test.obj2.changeValue.bind(test);
test.obj2.changeValue();`, because the problem stems from the `this` binding